# Values of one column in different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am a newbie to SQL and I need some help with a query

I have two amounts for one id in a table and I want the two amounts to be displayed in different columns but same row. The ID and Balance fields are coming from a basic `select` statement.

For example, this is the data I am getting

```
 ID        Balance
--------------------
2449079    2282.64
2449079    0.00
2449079    0.00
2452482    10556.96
2452482    0.00
2455481    2000.00
2455481    0.01
```

but I want to show the amount like mentioned below.  if there is only one balance amount then the remaining fields should be zero

```
 ID         BalAmt1   BalAmt2   BalAmt3    BalAmt4
----------------------------------------------------
2449079      2282.64    0         0          0
2452482      10556.96   0         0          0
2455481      2000      0.01       0          0
```

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2008 R2 or SQL Server 2012?  Don't tag both.

Comment: How are you determining which is Balance 1 and which is Balance 2, etc.?  SQL, by its own definition, represents *unordered sets*.  Without some kind of identifier or date column, there is no way to know which balance should be which.

Comment: just doing an order by on the balance in descending order and then put them in bal 1 and bal1. like the max value goes to balance 1 and the minimum goes to bal 4

Comment: we are using both 2008 and 2012. anything is fine for now so I tagged both

Comment: Use a ROW_NUMBER() along with a PIVOT

Comment: thank you rabbit. it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try what @Rabbit said. That should work. Here is a working sample

```
    Declare @table1 Table(Id int, Balance float)

    Insert into @table1 values (2449079, 2282.64)
    Insert into @table1 values (2449079, 0.00)
    Insert into @table1 values (2449079, 0.00)
    Insert into @table1 values (2452482, 10556.96)
    Insert into @table1 values (2452482, 0.00)
    Insert into @table1 values (2455481, 2000.64)
    Insert into @table1 values (2455481, 0.00)

    SELECT *
    FROM (
    SELECT Id, Balance,
    ('Bal' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id Order by Id asc) AS VARCHAR))AS row FROM @table1
    ) as s
    PIVOT
    (
      SUM(Balance)
      FOR row IN (Bal1, Bal2, Bal3, Bal4)
  )AS pvt
```

Comment: ya i did. it worked out. Thank you so much for all the help everyone.